Can an http request affect the Interaction to Next Paint (INP) of a page?
I am building a webapp and one of the concerns is to have a solid score in the core web vitals (LCP, CLS and INP).
Given it will be a single page application, INP is particular important.
However, I am wondering if HTTP requests (e.g. fetch) can affect this score or if they are, by design, yielding to the event loop (hence allowing a next paint to happen).
